# Solidity question about UsingLiquidityProtectionService

Tags: blockchain, solidity, cryptocurrency

Hi guys i'm new at Solidity development, I'm currently learning and reading a project called SporesToken https://github.com/Spores-Labs/spores-token-contracts/blob/master/contracts/SporesToken.sol

And i have a question about some kind of implementation

```
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/presets/ERC20PresetMinterPauser.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "./UsingLiquidityProtectionService.sol";

contract SporesToken is
    UsingLiquidityProtectionService(0xBA2bF7693E0903B373077ace7b002Bd925913df2),
    ERC20PresetMinterPauser,
    Ownable
```

From where comes the hash provided to UsingLiquidityProtectionService?
Maybe this is a noob question but i didn't get it..

Part of the content of ./UsingLiquidityProtectionService.sol

```
import "./external/UniswapV2Library.sol";
import "./external/UniswapV3Library.sol";
import "./IPLPS.sol";

abstract contract UsingLiquidityProtectionService {
    bool private unProtected = false;
    IPLPS private plps;
    uint64 internal constant HUNDRED_PERCENT = 1e18;
    bytes32 internal constant UNISWAP =
        0x96e8ac4277198ff8b6f785478aa9a39f403cb768dd02cbee326c3e7da348845f;
    bytes32 internal constant PANCAKESWAP =
        0x00fb7f630766e6a796048ea87d01acd3068e8ff67d078148a3fa3f4a84f69bd5;
    bytes32 internal constant QUICKSWAP =
        0x96e8ac4277198ff8b6f785478aa9a39f403cb768dd02cbee326c3e7da348845f;

    enum UniswapVersion {
        V2,
        V3
    }

    enum UniswapV3Fees {
        _005, // 0.05%
        _03, // 0.3%
        _1 // 1%
    }

    modifier onlyProtectionAdmin() {
        protectionAdminCheck();
        _;
    }

    constructor(address _plps) {
        plps = IPLPS(_plps);
    }

    function LiquidityProtection_setLiquidityProtectionService(IPLPS _plps)
        external
        onlyProtectionAdmin()
    {
        plps = _plps;
    }
```

I hope anyone here can answer me,
Kind Regards and thank you for your time.

Comment: Also what's the main usage of "UsingLiquityProtectionService" ? Does anyone know where can i source some documentation about this?

Answer (score 0):

> *From where comes the hash provided to UsingLiquidityProtectionService?*

The hash is a smart contract address passed to the `UsingLiquidityProtectionService` constructor ([link](https://github.com/Spores-Labs/spores-token-contracts/blob/master/contracts/UsingLiquidityProtectionService.sol#L35)).

From the context I can see it's [this contract](https://etherscan.io/address/0xBA2bF7693E0903B373077ace7b002Bd925913df2) on the Ethereum network. However, the contract authors didn't chose to verify the source code. So it's not possible to see the actual implementation without trying to decompile the bytecode. Just that the `UsingLiquidityProtectionService` expects the `0xBA2b...` contract to implement the [IPLPS](https://github.com/Spores-Labs/spores-token-contracts/blob/master/contracts/IPLPS.sol) interface.

Comment: But with this type of implementation what's is the point of passing this contract ? I have also see this in another coins but the same contract not verified so cannot read code.

Comment: @SaulDaSilva I don't know what are the contract authors' intentions. The `UsingLiquidityProtectionService` doesn't call any of the `IPLPS` methods, so it's unclear why they put it there. It might be an unfinished code and they might have planned to call the `IPLPS` functions later; or they might have forgotten to remove the setter & getter when they were deleting some other features.

Comment: I got it i don't know too author intentions, but for exemple if you see [link](https://github.com/Spores-Labs/spores-token-contracts/blob/master/contracts/UsingLiquidityProtectionService.sol) you will note that seem to be implemented.